# Is Compiz now embedded in Unity 3D?

Tags: compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is compiz embedded in Unity 3D by default in 11.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35128/is-compiz-embedded-in-unity-3d-by-default-in-11-04)

Does installing 11.04 mean that i don't have to install Compiz and CCSM provided my graphic card supports Unity 3D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont have to install compiz but to change setting within unity plugin it is easier to install ccsm