# Is compiz embedded in Unity 3D by default in 11.04?

Tags: compiz

Does installing 11.04 mean that i don't have to install Compiz and CCSM provided my graphic card supports Unity 3D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity 3D is a Compiz plugin, so it needs Compiz to run. CCSM is installed by default, too.

Comment: Way I'm reading these, CCSM isn't.https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/730991 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/237743 https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/744267/comments/4